# inheritence in java inherit variables?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, extends

As I understand the inherited class should also inherit variables, so why doesn't this code work?

```
public class a {
    private int num;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b d = new b();
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public b() {
        num = 5;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot inherit the private variables

Comment: @PradeepSimha as a matter of fact you can't inherit just any instance variables. they are only visible if they are marked public/protected/no-modifier

Comment: @PremGenError, yes I know that. So what? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`num` variable's access modifier is `private` and `private` members are not accessible out of own class so make it `protected` it will accessible from subclass.

```
public class a {
     protected int num;
     ...
}
```

Reference of [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 2):

> As i understand the inherited class should inherit also variables,

you got it wrong, `instance variables` are **not overriden** in sub-class. inheritence and polymorphism doesnt apply for instance fields. they are only visible in your sub-class if they are marked protected or public. currently you have super class variable marked private. no other class can access it. mark it either protected or public in-order for other class's to access it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class A{
    public int num=5;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b d = new b();
        d.c();
    }
}

class b extends A
{
    public void c() 
    {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

definitely this is what you need i think

Answer (score 1):

`private` scope can only be accessed by the containing class.

For this to work `num` would need to be declared `protected` scope.

However this would also make it accessible to other classes in the same package. My recommedation would be to create a `get` / `set` method in order to maintain proper encapsulation.

you could then access `num` in class `b` by calling `getNum()`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the **private** access modifier. If you use private to a **instance variable** or to a **method** it only can access **inside the class only**(even several classes include one source file). We can expose private variable to outside by using getters and setters. Following code will compile without an error

```
public class A {
    private int num;

public void setNum(int num)
{
     this.num = num;
}

public int getNum() 
{
      return num;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        B d = new B();
    }


  }
  class B extends A
       {

      public B()
 {

        SetNum(5);
        System.out.println(getNum());
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to private members of the base classes  from the subclass. Only the members with modifiers of private/protected